# SQL Server Agent unable to view network drives

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

I am unable to get agent jobs to output to a network path. I have pushed the IT guy to set up a domain authenticated user that logs in when the agent starts. That login does have access to the domain and is able to see the network drives. If I set the location of the output file to be the local c: then this works without issue. However if I set the drive to be a network location I get the following message;

```
[SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 0)Unable to open Step output file. The step succeeded.
```

Any help would be very much appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by "user that logs in when the agent starts"? Is it the account running SQL Server Agent service you can see on `services.msc`?

Comment: this link contains all you need to know about SQL Agent: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/setting-up-your-sql-server-agent-correctly/
As Ronaldo said, you need to make sure the service account running SQL Agent does have write permission in the remote folder.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the help. UNC file paths was the solution.

> Another thing to check is that you refer to the output location with a UNC path instead of a mapped letter drive. Letter drive mappings aren't reliable from something running as a service.  – [Doug Deden](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/170408/doug-deden) 2 days ago

> Here is some more information regarding mapped drives and services: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182750/map-a-network-drive-to-be-used-by-a-service – [G.Smith](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/146171/g-smith) 2 days ago